# How to access data with keyname with "."

Tags: javascript

I'm having the following problem when I'm trying to access a data that has a key with a ".".

```
data: {
 car.model: "Mercedez",
 car.color: "Blue"
}

//Javascript

var model = result.data.car.model;
var model = result.data.'car.model';
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined"

Is there a way i can read the car.model and car.color?

Comment: This isn't really an answer, by why don't you structure data as `data: { car: { model: "Mercedez", color: "Blue" } }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the data using an array syntax

```
var model = result.data['car.model'];
```

Comment: For google purposes, this is referred to as `bracket notation` (or square bracket notation). When you access a property with a `.` (`result.data`, for instance), it's referred to as `dot notation`.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your data to this:

```
data: 
{
    car:
    {
      model: "Mercedez",
      color: "Blue"
    }
}
```

Then you can access your values like this:

```
var model = data.car.model;
var color = data.car.color;
```